# Oracle: Changing size of variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a Oracle database. There's a table having a column that's called UC_ADMIN_TYPE. Currently it's set to be 1 char.

So for e.g., this field will have a value of A, B, C, D,....

Now we want to change this to AA, BB, CC,......like that

So basically it should support 2 characters.

Can i go ahead and change the 1 char of current UC_ADMIN_TYPE to 2 char?

Or is it possible to fit 2 chars in the current UC_ADMIN_TYPE (1 char) itself?

If i need to change it to 2 char, what's the SQL for that?

Is there any other implications of that change?

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you're doing, you'll want to switch to the `varchar2` data type.  The `char` type will pad your string with empty spaces, it can lead to some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest modifying the datatype of the column to varchar2

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype
```

Or maybe char(n) where n is the maximum length of char.

[Difference between char and varchar](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types)

Comment: `char` is almost always a bad choice.

Comment: Because the values of `char` columns are always padded to the defined length (using a space character). So if you store the value `'x'` into a `char(10)` column, Oracle will store `'x         '`. If you compare that e.g. with `varchar` column, that contains `'x'` the comparison fails. `char` has absolutely no advantages over `varchar` but has several disadvantages.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh ok thanks for reminding. Much appreciated